# MySQL COUNT(*) GROUP BY HAVING COUNT=?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, having-clause

This my Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T1
 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T2
 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T3
 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
GROUP BY RoomType
HAVING COUNT( total ) = 4
```

Output result

```
count   Toys            date
3   Bibi        2012-06-26
4   Baba            2012-06-26
```

How can i get MYSQL to show results only for count=4

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T1
     WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26' AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
     GROUP BY RoomType
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T2
     WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26' AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
     GROUP BY RoomType
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T3
     WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
    GROUP BY RoomType) AS src
WHERE total = 4;
```

Please, note, that for proper data groupping you *must* have all columns either in the `GROUP BY` clause or as arguments to the aggregate functions. It is MySQL feature to allow you to avoid this restriction, but it might lead you to the unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

You need group by first then union the result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T1
 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
 GROUP BY RoomType HAVING COUNT( *) = 4
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T2
 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
 GROUP BY RoomType HAVING COUNT( * ) = 4
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, toys, date FROM T3
 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-26'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0')
 GROUP BY RoomType HAVING COUNT( * ) = 4
```